# ¿Cómo ejecutar un script específico en una ruta específica de PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Espero se encuentren todos bien, estoy trabajando con PHP(codeigniter) y el problema que tengo es que tengo un script con los gráficos estadísticos, pero dicho script se ejecuta en todas las ruta que tengo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se ejecute únicamente en esta ruta?

```
http://localhost/ci3/dashboard
```

**Mi base_url es la siguiente**

```
http://localhost/ci3
```

**Y mi footer con los scripts es el siguiente**

```
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>components/scripts/clientes.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>components/scripts/servicio_tecnico.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>components/scripts/ploteo.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>components/scripts/graficas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**El script que deseo que se ejecute en el dashboard es este**

```
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>components/scripts/graficas.js"></script>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hmmm a ver ese script tecnicamente no deberia estarse ejecutando en todas tus paginas si solo lo tienes linkeada a uno, quiza hay algo que estas omitiendo?, por ejemplo, estas usando laravel o algun framework?, Estas acaso requiriendo sin querer en las otras paginas el script al hacer `import` o `require`?, verifica esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca he tocado CodeIgniter y la verdad no se si debería responder esta pregunta sin haber hecho testing de lo que voy a publicar a continuación, pero, creo que esto puede ayudarte.

Asumiendo que estás usando el footer en varias páginas puedes usar un if para comprobar que en efecto se encuentre **dashboard** y así ejecutarlo únicamente cuando se encuentre allí.

Simplemente busqué como funcionaba el `current_url()` y `base_url()`, si en teoría hacen lo que leí, debería funcionarte.

```
<?php if( current_url() == base_url('dashboard') ): ?>

    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>components/scripts/graficas.js"></script>
    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: En efecto compa, me  has ayudado con mi problema, te agradezo mucho y funcionó correctamente, muchas gracias